# How to disable On Click Listener created in onCreate, in onPause? (In Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

In Android Studio, I am trying to open the second activity when corresponding button is pressed.However, I cannot reach that listener that I create in "onCreate" from onPause. I am following an approach like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View.OnClickListener openSecondPage = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button button_newPage = findViewById(R.id.button_newpage);
            button_newPage.setText("Clicked");
            Intent secondPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class );
            startActivity(secondPage);

        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button_newPage = findViewById(R.id.button_newpage);
        button_newPage.setOnClickListener(openSecondPage);

    }
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Button button_newPage = findViewById(R.id.button_newpage);
        //Destroy the on click listener
        button_newPage.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    }
```

Also user will be able to come back to main activity and then go back to the second activity again. In that case I don't want to open a new activity. Instead I want to open previously created activity. For that case should I create a `onResume()` method and in that, call `startActivity(secondPage)`. But in that case, since the `secondPage` is declared in `onStart` I won't be able to use in `onResume`. How can I handle that situation?
So there are actually 2 questions.. sorry about that, I didn't want to open 2 different questions for it.

Answer (score 1):

Put `Button button_newPage = findViewById(R.id.button_newpage);` and `button_newPage.setOnClickListener(openSecondPage);` inside onResume instead of onCreate, like so:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Button button_newPage = findViewById(R.id.button_newpage);
        button_newPage.setOnClickListener(openSecondPage);

    }
```

That should solve at least part of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in that case, for the first time the program initiated, will I be able to go to the "second page"? Because there will be no on click listener in onCreate anymore.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Android lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEf4T.jpg)? Your program will always run through the onResume method (and execute whatever code is inside it) after onCreate.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with the Android Studio, not just the lifecycle :). Thanks that makes sense now

Comment: But yet again, that will call the Intent secondPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class ); line again when the button is pressed. So I need to check if there is any SecondActivity exists before that line. Otherwise, that line will create a new activity instead of going to the created one.